# Embarcadero C++Builder android service example

Tags: android, service, c++builder

Do anyone know of working examples using android services in Embarcadero C++Builder XE8/Seattle/Berlin ?

I see there are many Delphi Examples,  but I need examples in C++.

RG

Comment: The existing Delphi examples should be easily translatable.

Comment: Delphi and C++Builder share the same RTL, VCL, and FMX frameworks, so anything that works in Delphi will (usually) work in C++Builder as well, just translate the syntax from Pascal to C++ as needed. Also, C++Builder has the added benefit that you can use Delphi `.pas` files in C++ projects, and it will generate C++ `.hpp` header files so your C++ code can call into the Delphi code. So, if you wanted to avoid translating code, you could theoretically just compile the Delphi code as-is with a thin C++ wrapper around it.

Comment: Well, at the moment I am stuck in AppMethod 1.17 for a couple of months until its license runs out... in this version I only have C++ to use. My Delphi is as bad as my french though... ;) I'll make a try. ..